# wp_register_script - illegal string offset

Tags: php, plugin-development

I've noticed that in my plugin code there is something wrong. I'm getting an illegal string offset error in the dependency delcaration of the `wp_register_script` function

```php
                wp_register_script(
                    'map-autocomplete',
                    'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tomickigrzegorz/autocomplete@1.8.3/dist/js/autocomplete.min.js',
                    ['map','map-config'],
                    false,
                    true
                );
                wp_enqueue_script('map-autocomplete');
```

Is there something wrong into the array?

Comment: I don’t see anything obviously wrong. Are you sure this is the relevant code? What’s the full error?

Comment: The error that is displayed is `Illegal string offset 'map'` but the code is ok, not sure why this occur, it's a warning, not really an error

Comment: Are you running an extremely old PHP version?

Comment: I'm on local dev machine, on php 7.4

Comment: Well the error doesn’t make any sense. Either this isn’t the actual code in use or it’s not the code that’s throwing the error because I can’t see anything in this code that would throw that error.

Comment: yes, it's strange. In my dev setup I just have my custom plugin code, I need to investigate to understand why this error is occuring